# Quick watch window not showing the variable value in Visual Studio for C++/CLI project

Tags: c++, .net, visual-studio-2008

I know that Visual Studio support for C++/CLI is terrible. But I am getting a weird issue when doing a *Quick watch*. The variable which I am watching is in the scope and it has value. But VS says, the variable is not in the scope. See the image

[Quick watch problem in C==/CLI http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/95471b8cb4.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/95471b8cb4.png)

It would be great if someone can suggest a workaround. Or is this a bug with VS?

Answer (score 5):

I actually made it work by these steps, not sure why this should be the solution though.

1. checking enabling .net source stepping and enable source server.
   [image: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=987ubn&s=3#.WAM_D5MrK8o]
2. it then loaded all symbols
3. made a clean build, removed it again and enabled just my code
4. clean build, voila i got correct debug symbols again!

Comment: image does not exist anymore

Comment: I know like this is 11 years later, but I've got involved with some legacy work on VS2008. Suddenly, I couldn't see the values of some global arrays. I set Enable .NET FW source stepping and also Enable source server support. It downloaded symbols for the .NET libraries and now I can watch my globals again. Re-enabling "Enable Just My Code" screwed it up again.

Answer (score 2):

Is this in Debug or Release? Release builds, even with PDB support, are notorious for poor watches.

Comment: a "debug release"? a "debug build" you mean?

Comment: That was the correct answer for me. I was literally pulling my hair out and swearing loudly! Thank you אסף!

Answer (score 1):

I got the exact same problem. Its in debug mode, ONLY on websites, other projects (console, webapplications) are fine. I use c#, Visual Studio 2008, asp.net 3.5 SP1.

I also get strange types in the locals window.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this article -> [Out Of Context Variables In Visual Studio 2010 Debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8672620/out-of-context-variables-in-visual-studio-2010-debugger)

This seems to be a PostSharp bug that's fixable using the latest release