# Visual Studio Watch window not taking into account usings

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, debugging, mono.cecil

I have the following code in a view model:

```
public Point Location
{
    get
    {
        var rangePixels = Range * PixelsPerMile;
        var xCoordinate = OwnLocation.X * MapScale + rangePixels * Math.Cos(Theta);
        var yCoordinate = OwnLocation.Y * MapScale - rangePixels * Math.Sin(Theta);
        return new Point(xCoordinate, yCoordinate);
    }
}
```

One of the usings at the top of the code file is `System`, which contains `Math`.

If I view `Math.Sin(Theta)` in the Watch window (by selecting the code, right clicking, and choosing "Add Watch"), I get the following error:

> The name 'Math' does not exist in the current context

What I want to know is:

1. Is this expected/default behavior for Visual Studio 2010? I could swear this never used to be a problem, but maybe it's always worked that way and I somehow never noticed.
2. If it's not normal to get this error, any thoughts on what the problem could be? There are a million settings in Visual Studio, and I wouldn't know where to begin.

I should note this question is vaguely similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8672620/out-of-context-variables-in-visual-studio-2010-debugger), but I'm not having any issues mousing over my local variables, and I'm not using PostSharp.

**Edit**

I just tried resetting all my Visual Studio settings backs to default, and I'm still getting the same error. If someone wants to try a simple test in Visual Studio, I just want to know if you get an error if you add a watch for `Math.Sin(1)`.

**Edit 2**

Here are a couple screen captures to show what I'm experiencing:

[image: Adding Math.Sin(1) to watch]

[image: Showing error for Watch]

**Edit 3**

Interestingly, intellisense works if I type `Math.` into the Watch window, but if I complete the expression, I still get the error:

[image: Showing intellisense working]

**Edit 4**

To address BACON's questions:

1. I get the same behavior with QuickWatch and Immediate.
2. Closing and reopening all the windows does not solve the problem.
3. I'm using Visual Studio 2010 Professional (version 10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel)
4. I tried targeting .NET 4.0 Client Profile and full .NET 4.0. Made no difference. I created a Console App (rather than a WPF app) targeting .NET 4.0 Client Profile, and finally, the error did not occur. So, WPF may be an issue (or WPF with some third-party libraries). (Will check on that next.)

Comment: What happens if you add a watch on `System.Math.Sin(1)`?

Comment: @BACON, that works fine. (It gets to be a pain though for deeper namespaces.)

Comment: Do Quick Watch and the Immediate Window exhibit the same behavior?  If you completely close all Watch windows and reopen them from the Debug menu does that affect anything?  What edition of Visual Studio 2010 are you using?  Do you have Service Pack 1 installed?  Does this happen regardless of which version of .NET your application is targeting?

Comment: @BACON, See my edit (Edit 4). None of your suggestions solved the problem, but your last one gave me the idea to try a console app (instead of a WPF), and that at least got the error to stop happening.

Comment: @BACON, Figured out the problem (see my answer below). Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears that the culprit is a third-party library that performs IL weaving (Fody.PropertyChanged).

If I create a new WPF project without this library, I'm able to use `Math.Sin()` in the Watch window. Once I install `PropertyChanged`, I start getting the "not available in this context" error.

Thanks to @BACON for leading me down the right path to figuring this out.

Here's a link to an issue I posted on the PropertyChanged site:

http://code.google.com/p/propertychanged/issues/detail?id=6&thanks=6&ts=1330494634

**Edit**

And subsequently, it turns out this is probably a bug in Mono-Cecil, which PropertyChanged uses:

https://github.com/jbevain/cecil/issues/90

Answer (score 1):

I did this in a litte test app, in the constructor..

[image]

Trying to put a watch on Math lets me see the values of E and PI.
You cannot put one on Sin.
Putting one on val works just fine.

So, no, I don't think that it's quite normal, unless you clicked on the wrong name.  I.e., not the variable, but the "Sin" portion...

Here is where I highlighted the entire thing...

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I need to know what happens if you do a watch for `Math.Sin(val)`. Doing a watch for `val` alone is not my problem.

Comment: Hmm... well, I highlighted the entire thing "Math.Sin(val)", and got a watch, showing the value to be 0.84147....

Sorry for not reading the question very well.

Comment: Just added an edit to my question, hopefully will make it more clear what I'm asking.

Comment: Okay, so something is definitely messed up with my Visual Studio, hmm. +1 for testing this out for me.