# Local variables appear out of scope in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I hope this isn't redundant of other posts, but I hope I can help someone else. I was finding that local variables in my VS2010 .NET 4.0 project were not inspectable. My breakpoint would stop, but I couldn't mouse over and view variable/object properties. And when I put that variable in the Watch window, it appeared out of scope. I have had this happen before periodically, but never knew why. I found the solution.

First, my solution is different from what was posted here:
[Out Of Context Variables In Visual Studio 2010 Debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8672620/out-of-context-variables-in-visual-studio-2010-debugger)

Here is a screenshot of what I was seeing:
[image]

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 3):

The solution is simple: In the Build tab of the VS Project Properties, there is an "Optimize code" checkbox. You have to UNCHECK that. I don't know how it got checked in the first place, I don't think I checked it. But when I unchecked that, everything worked again.

Comment: Are you sure you compile and debug your code in the DEBUG configuration? Note that DEBUG has optimization **turned off** by default, while RELEASE has it **turned on** by default.

Comment: The VS Project Properties? Where's that?