# C# run-time completely skips lines of code - why?

Tags: c#

I put a break point on the line indicated below.  When execution hits it nothing happens.  The line and the next one after that are completely skipped.  Can someone tell me what is occurring here?  I can't figure this one out.

```
string correctName;
string testingonetwothree;
int indexOfSpace = 0;
TextInfo storeLocation = new CultureInfo("en-US", false).TextInfo;
foreach(StoreLocation sL in storeLocations)
{
    correctName = storeLocation.ToTitleCase(sL.name);
    correctName = correctName.Substring(9);
<BreakPoint Here>    indexOfSpace = correctName.IndexOf(" "); //I added this line but during runtime it's completely ignored. - I placed a break point and nothing happens.
    testingonetwothree = "Hello " + "world"; //After that I got paranoid and added this line to see if I was just being crazy.  This line is skipped as well.
    correctName = correctName.ToLower();
    correctName = char.ToUpper(correctName[0]) + correctName.Substring(1);
    sL.name = correctName;
    sL.state = LookUpFullStateName(sL.state);
}
return storeLocations;
```

Comment: Are you running in debug or release mode? Since those variables aren't used afterwards the compiler probably just gets rid of them.

Comment: How large is the array of TextInfo storeLocations? Are there any elements in it?

Comment: Perhaps the compiler is removing unnecessary code.

Comment: Are you sure the loop itself is running? Place a breakpoint outside the loop, and see if storeLocations has the values you expect.

Comment: Is code optimization [turned on](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12663257/1997232) ?

Comment: @mikeTheLiar - I think you're correct.  As soon as I added some more code after that line referencing the variable that line did seem to matter.  That was strange. I've never seen the run-time just overtly ignore code before. I wasn't prepared for that.

Comment: @KevinWinters, if `storeLocations` is empty, it will skip everything inside the foreach loop.