# Visual Studio 2012 - Locals not shown

Tags: visual-studio-2012, fortran, intel-fortran

I am using Visual Studio 2012 with the Intel Fortran Compiler XE 13.0 (from Parallel Studio 2013) to code in Fortran.

When debugging a project, the "Locals" and "Auto" windows don't show any variable. Similarly, when hovering over a variable name in the code, I don't get any datatip showing its value. Lastly, when trying to evaluate a variable or expression in the Watches I always get an "Unable to evaluate expression". So, as far as I understand, there's some problem involving debugger symbols or something like this.

Here's what I tried:

- restarting VS and Windows
- creating a new solution with default configuration
- checking the Debugging options for any obvious setting which could case this
- followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1081584/quick-watch-window-not-showing-the-variable-value-in-visual-studio-for-c-cli-p), even if it looks like it's for a slightly different problem (VS recognizes a local variable, but saying it's out of scope)
- repairing my Intel Parallel Studio XE 2013 installation

I never enabled optimization. Here's [a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYcfL.jpg) so that you can clearly see what it's going on here.

P.S: as a last hint, I found a [similar bug](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6133b9d0-81c6-4e30-bfe5-5b3d6e104300/no-debug-info-for-local-variables-vs2010-vc?forum=vsdebug) affecting VS2010, but 1) yeah, I've got VS2012 and I suppose it should have been fixed 2) it affects C++ (don't know if this matters though) 3) the patch is not directly available online.

Comment: http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/328615

Comment: @HansPassant: thanks, that worked. For some reason I failed to notice the updates by Intel.